# Problems with Netflix Streaming, DDWRT, and Xbox 360

Tags: connection, streaming, dd-wrt, netflix, xbox360

Basically, I have been having problems getting Netflix Streaming to play on my Xbox 360 with my DD-WRT router. The thing is, it will play some movies, sometimes. For example, the other day, I could not get it to play Nikita, now today, it will play Nikita perfectly fine, but it is unable to play Being Human.

Typically, when I attempt to play a show, it will either fully play without errors, or will not be able to load at all. When it doesn't load, it will load to 7%, remain there for a while, then move to 9%, then respond with an error message saying that there is an error with my home network connection.

```
An Internet or home network connection problem is preventing playback. 
Please check your Internet connection and try again or visit 
www.netflix.com/tvhelp for guidance. (code: R8212)
```

Now, when I attempt to use the non-DDWRT router, it will connect and play perfectly every time. So I believe the error is somewhere in the settings of the DD-WRT. I have attempted the following to correct this:

- Set a static IP address for the Xbox 360
- Forwarded ports 3074, 88, and 53 (both TCP and UDP) to the Xbox
- Enabled UPnP
- Disabled CTS Protection mode
- Disabled Frame Burst
- Disabled Afterburner
- Placed the Xbox in DMZ
- Enabling QoS and adding the Xbox IP to the QoS
- Disabled the DD-WRT firewall

I would really like to have Netflix work correctly with the DD-WRT router because I do like a lot of the benefits that it gives. I use the ability to add static IP addresses to specific MAC addresses, port forwarding to those specific IP addresses, and the automated DynamicDNS integration.

Specs:
Xbox 360 S with Gold Live membership
Active Netflix account

Router 1:
Linksys WRT54GS
Firmware: DD-WRT v24-sp2 (10/10/09) micro

Router 2:
Belkin F7D2301 v1
Default firmware

So, my overall question is, what can I do to fix this problem, to allow the Xbox 360 to connect to play all the shows from Netflix Streaming?

Answer (score 0):

Ok,.....
Start over! reset to factory defaults.

For one if port forwarding is setup then disable UPnP, don't use both at the same time.
If you manually forward ports set that up before changing anything else to make sure you get them working correctly, then you can tweak everything else.

I have spent numerous hours reading through forums trying to get the best setup for my xbox live.  I failed until recently, I thought I was doing things right, but most forum posters don't know crap, me included.

But if you dig deep enough you find some from people that know what they are talking about, who actually explain why UPnP and port forwarding should not be enabled at the same time.

UPnP, Port Forward, or DMZ,   ONLY ONE at a time!!

Then I learned that DNS servers and the MTU setting also make a huge difference, once i got those correct and properly setup qos....

OMG!!!!! Best online gaming experience ever!!!!!

Best mtu setting for me was 1452 but it may be different for you.
Try DNS server 8.8.8.8

And don't forget to set a static IP address, for my dd-wrt the lease time must be left blank